# How to get the value of input from different div in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's the html:

```
<div id="parent">
 <div id ="child1">
    <div id="subchild1">
        <input type="text" name="first" value="3">
    </div>
 </div>
 <div id ="child2">
    <div id="subchild2">
        <input type="text" name="second" value="7">
    </div>
 </div>
 <div id ="child3">
    <div id="subchild3">
        <input type="text" name="third" value="8">
    </div>
 </div>
</div>

<div id="result">
```

Here's the Jquery:

```
$(function(){
 var len = $('#parent > div').length;

 for(var i=0; i < len; i++){
    var a = $('#subchild'+ [i + 1]).find('input');
    $('#result').html(a);
 }
});
```

It always get's the last value. I tried all my best but here's the only code I can do. Maybe someone that can help me.

**[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aldrin27/z4yfohao/)**

Comment: What value are you trying to get?

Comment: `$('#result').append(a);` instead of  `$('#result').html(a);`

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can use `append` but code shown doesn't indicate what expectations are and neither does explanation. Using `append()` or `html()` will move the elements

Comment: But what If I want to use console.log(a.val()); It shows nothing.

Comment: `console.log(a.val())` works fine  http://jsfiddle.net/z4yfohao/2/ Still getting variety of answers because objective/expectations are not clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want is values the following creates an array of those values  and uses `join()` to separate them in the target div:

```
var values = $('[id^=subchild] input').map(function(){
   return this.value;
}).get();

$('#result').html( values.join('<br>') );
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ubxr4aL3/)**</kbd>

Comment: I've been doing `.map` function. This is exactly what i need. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
$('#result').html(a);
```

to

```
$('#result').append(a);
```

.html() replaces everything within that element where .append() just adds to what's already there.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("[name='first']").each(function(){ alert(this.value) })
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is you're using `$('#result').html(a);` as this code will replace the previous value and take only the last result. Use [`.append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) instead like below code :

```
$(function () {
  var len = $('#parent > div').length;

  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    // get value of input text
    var a = $('#subchild' + [i + 1]).find('input').val();
    // every time got value, append those value into result element 
    // now input value available, see console
    console.log(a);
    $('#result').append(a);
  }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/6xkh6y8a/)

Comment: Can you show me how to see the inputted values in console.log()? There's no return value when I use that.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're only seeing the last result is because you're equating the html each time and not concatenating it.

```
$(function(){
 var len = $('#parent > div').length;

 for(var i=0; i < len; i++){
    var a = $('#subchild'+ [i + 1]).find('input');
    $('#result').append(a);
 }
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1L5v4q3c/

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this? `values` holds all 3 values.

```js
$(function() {
  var len = $('#parent > div').length;

  var values = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var a = $('#subchild' + [i + 1]).find('input').val();
    values.push(a);
  }
  
  alert(values);
  $('#result').html(values.toString());

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child1">
    <div id="subchild1">
      <input type="text" name="first" value="3">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="child2">
    <div id="subchild2">
      <input type="text" name="first" value="7">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="child3">
    <div id="subchild3">
      <input type="text" name="first" value="8">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="result"></div>
```